# Is there a maximum number of namespace levels allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Question out of curiosity. I have successfully created a 300 levels deep namespace nesting.
Visua studio happily suggest "a.a.a.a.a[...].a.theclass as a quick fix if i enter the class name buried below those layers of namespacing.

Does anyone know if there is an actual limit as for how deeply nested namespaces can be?

No case where I'd need it, just curious.

Comment: I'd probably aim the [Nurf Cannon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7blisWNovEQ) at the developer who tried to _double-digit_ nesting from a readability-perspective let along 300

Comment: @Micky: Even if you were working on the idea of a project where every single class is named "a"? ;-)

Comment: Ah well, then we have the _Special Nurf Cannon_ for that ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From documentation - [Namespace Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dx91cw5.aspx)

> You can declare one namespace within another. **There is no strict
>   limit to the levels of nesting you can declare**, but remember that
>   when other code accesses the elements declared in the innermost
>   namespace, it must use a qualification string that contains all the
>   namespace names in the nesting hierarchy.

Comment: "No strict limit" implies that ther is some form of limit. If there is, I wonder if it's based on number of levels alone, or if for example namespace name length will make a difference.

Comment: I believe it meant, there is no limit, but hundreds of level of nesting would *probably* be useless.

Comment: It may be so. I might try with a thousand levels if i get the time. I am impressed by how well bilt vs2015 seems to handle nonsense like this anyway. :-)